# Echo php content into API javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, api

I would need to echo php variables (from the server and related to service behaviour) into javascript. For example, `"ssl" => "true"` and adapt accordingly in javascript. The thing is I'm doing this for some API files I'm writing and I want the client to have direct access to these files `(<script src="... .js">)` and this forces me to hardcode info that might change in the future across multiple file references. What I'd like to do was something like this, is it possible? **(the content to fetch must remain completely private - from the server folders to the php script files - and so it is really not an option to fetch this info using javascript)**:

**api.js**

```
<? //PHP here. (I know...)
(...)
?>
//some javascript
var is_secure = <? echo "true"/"false" ?>
(...)
```

So that when doing `<script src="api.js"/>` the user only fetches:

```
var is_secure = "true";
(...)
```

or

```
var is_secure = "false";
(...)
```

Any idea on how I could do something similar? Thank you very much...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Should a user be able to fetch this data you are writing out with PHP, or does it need to remain private. That part of the question is a bit vague.

Comment: You would need to add an apache handler to parse js files as PHP, or name the file `something.js.php`, then it would render accordingly.

Comment: Is that 'echo "true"/"false" ' working ? You have  a '/' between, for me is something like true divided with false... and will be an exception because is division by 0

Comment: @ScottJohnson Ok I'm sorry If I was vague, what I want is for the user to receive the data (and see it, of course) but only the data itself and not the sources. For example, my file is in `secrets / these_are_secrets.php`. I don't want the user to access these_are_secrets.php on the client side but I want to span these content into the javascript file... for example, "foursquare_key": "af0jkIF9301F0M"...

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ I meant "true" or "false", it was only hypothetical for the examples below

Comment: @AndrewCoder I'm on nginx. Would something.js.php actually be parsed? And is this behaviour "professionally" or traditionally acceptable?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately, I've never used nginx.  But I don't see why you couldn't parse PHP against any file extension as long as the httpd is configured to do so.  Or just use raw PHP and send out appropriate headers with the output like in the answer provided by @Sakuto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create your PHP file with this line before everything :

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

Comment: `<script src="file.php">` with the above line of code in the `.php` file. That should be an excellent solution.

Comment: The js extension is less relevant at the client level.  When you add a JS to a webpage, you explicitly declare it as such `type='text/javascript'` so the client should handle it fine even with a different extension.

Comment: You can just use the simple script tag to call your page, even if it's a php page, just specify "text/javascript" in your script tag.

Comment: This is amazing @Sakuto ... Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I did misunderstood the question. If you want js in an php file, you should do it like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
```

*OLD ANSWER:*

I don't know if you know, but client can't see your php code...

So if You'd:

```
echo "Something"
```

The client would only see Something.

It's not clear, what you're trying to do...

If you don't want to see Something when you go directly into your "secret" php page, then you should do it like this:

JS:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'secretfile.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {apiRequest: 1},
        success: function (response) {
            yourVar = response;
        }
});
```

PHP:

```
If ($_POST['apiRequest']==1){
    echo "Something";
}
```

yourVar would be = "Something"

If you'd go to this page, it wouldn't display anything;

Comment: I don't know if you know, but you completely misunderstood the problem